# Is there a way to #define a C macro that is only defined while in an Eclipse editor window?

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt, iar

I'm using Eclipse Galileo with CDT for C development targeting embedded devices.

Like so many other compilers targeted at µcontrollers, the IAR compiler uses some non-standard variable types that Eclipse/CDT doesn't recognize and flags them as problems.  Since these variable types are the foundations of other variable types I use the problem cascades to the point that just about every line using variables declared with the non-standard types are flagged as having syntax problems, even when the syntax is correct.  It's not a critical problem, but it is definitely a nuisance.

1. Is there a setting within Eclipse/CDT where I can add non-standard syntax, or...
2. Is there some predefined macro within Eclipse/CDT that I can access with something like `#ifdef SECRET_ECLIPSE_MACRO ...` for conditionally setting or clearing a macro with the string of the offending variable type definition?

Comment: Defining something like `-DECLIPSE_INDEXER` for the Eclipse indexer would also solve this problem. See my answer here for exactly how to do so: [How can I convince Eclipse CDT that a macro is defined for source code editing and code completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66094447/4561887)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can go the other way around. Define a `NOT_ECLIPSE` macro when you compile your code, and check for its non-existence in your code. If it's not defined, you're in Eclipse.

Comment: +1, but I think one can even go one step further. The compiler in question probably identifies itself through a macro `__IAR___`, whatever. One could just put dummy defines for the types inside `#ifndef __IAR__`.

Comment: @JensGustedt:  +1 You are correct.  [This page](http://predef.sourceforge.net/precomp.html) has a list of many different compiler's predefined macros, including `__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__`.

Answer (score 2):

> > > Is there some predefined macro within Eclipse/CDT that I can access

Yes, there are many.

See this page.
http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_prop_build_variables.htm

Don't forget to check the 'SHow system variables' option.

Answer (score 1):

```
__CDT_PARSER__
```

is defined during CDT editor preprocessing stage (works at least with Indigo SR2)

Comment: See also here for a more-thorough answer on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41388347/4561887.